# Identify unique values from list of lists, with each list having at least n unique elements

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of list

```
measurements = [[1,2,3],[1,3,5,6],[4,6,7,8]]
```

I need to retrieve N unique elements from each list with respect to other list. Say N = 2. The result must be

```
result = [[1,2],[5,6],[7,8]]
```

Of course there can be other combinations but I need only one such.
Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want unique elements, sets are the way to go.
to get unique values from lists of list try below:

```
>>> measurements = [[1,2,3],[1,3,5,6],[4,6,7,8]]
>>> result = set(x for l in measurements for x in l)
>>> result
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

OR

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> measurements = [[1,2,3],[1,3,5,6],[4,6,7,8]]
>>> print(set(chain(*measurements)))
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
measurements = [[1,2,3],[1,3,5,6],[4,6,7,8]]
result = []
N = 2
for x in measurements:
    result.append(random.sample(x,N)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list of lists to a list of sets first, and then find unique elements in each set by performing `set.difference` over other sets with `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
measurements = [[1,2,3],[1,3,5,6],[4,6,7,8]]
sets = list(map(set, measurements))
diffs = [reduce(set.difference, sets[:i] + sets[i+1:], sets[i]) for i in range(len(sets))]
```

`diffs` would become:

```
[{2}, {5}, {8, 4, 7}]
```

It would then be trivial to obtain `N` items from each set in the `diffs` list:

```
result = []
for diff in diffs:
    result.append([])
    for _ in range(2): # assuming N = 2
        try:
            result[-1].append(diff.pop())
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

`result` would become:

```
[[2], [5], [8, 4]]
```

Note that the expected output in your question, `[[1,2],[5,6],[7,8]]`, is incorrect, because neither `1` nor `6` is unique.

Comment: The result is correct, what I meant to say was that the final list obtained (i.e result) must be unique (non repeating elements) but it must be ensured that each sublist has at least 2 elements.

Comment: But if there aren't enough items in a sublist, the OP doesn't mention what to do with the sublist, so I chose to leave the sublist as is.

Comment: @blhsing, i believe the question needs to be reframed , as the OP's desired request is to read all the sublists and get only the elements which are not into the other list an unique in a broader context is to see all the unique element sets in the whole list.

Comment: @pygo To me, "N unique elements from each list with respect to other list" is fairly clear except for the case when there aren't N unique elements in a sublist. I certainly don't think it's the way you interpret it in your answer, which is quite far from the OP's expected output. Of course it would help if the OP can offer some clarification and more sample input/output.

Comment: @blhsing, that's what i understood, but more clarification and code concept if OP can brought up to the question that be will easy to understand to all, expected output so far doesn't seems to be valid.